# aftersavefunc JQGrid called before call to backend

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with inline editing with custom buttons, I'm trying to show a custom message or popup if the save was unsuccesul:

```
editurl: '@Url.Action("UpdateMatrixData")',
                datatype: "json",
                postData: {
                    sp: function () { return getFilter(); }
                },
                postData: {
                    StartDate: function () { return $("#StartDate").val(); },
                    EndDate: function () { return $('#EndDate').val(); },
                },
                gridComplete: function ()
                {
                    var ids = jQuery("#evGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
                        {
                            var cl = ids[i];
                            be = "<input style='height:15px;width:15px;' title='Edit selected row' type='button' class='EditGridButton'  onclick=\"jQuery('#evGrid').editRow('" + cl + "');\" />"
                            se = "<input style='height:15px;width:15px;' title='Save row' type='button' class='SaveButton'  onclick=\"jQuery('#evGrid').saveRow('" + cl + "', '', '', '', reload());\" />"  // dont Need to refesh grid after saving row - call reload function
                            ce = "<input style='height:15px;width:15px;' title='Cancel row editing' type='button' class='CancelButton'  onclick=\"jQuery('#evGrid').restoreRow('" + cl + "');\" />";
                            jQuery("#evGrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be + se + ce });
                        }
                },

 function reload(rowid, response) {

            alert(response)
            $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' });
            $(this).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1 }]);
        }
```

the response is null however? and its being called before the updateMatrixData method gets called?

updateMatrixData returns Json(true) or Json(false)

```
return Json(isSucess);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main error in the usage of

```
onclick=\"jQuery('#evGrid').saveRow('" + cl + "', '', '', '', reload());\"
```

instead of

```
onclick=\"jQuery('#evGrid').saveRow('" + cl + "', '', '', '', reload);\"
```

`reload` is callback function which will be called by jqGrid. If you use `reload()`, then your code calls `reload` mit empty parameters, before jqGrid do that (jqGrid don't get the reference of the function at all and get `undefined` returned from `reload()` instead).

Comment: @Standage: You are welcome! In general many parts of your code should be changed. Modifying of the grid content in the loop using `setRowData` is the slowest way to fill the grid. Instead of that one should better to use custom formatter or predefined formatters like `formatter: "actions"`. On the other side, sometime one has no time to rewrite old code and it's important just to make it working.